# Add new Worksheet c# (doubts)

Tags: c#, excel, vsto, com-interop, worksheet

I'm working with **C#** and **Excel** for the first time ... And I would like to know ***how can I add a new worksheet in a Workbook***. I have been reading some posts but none works for me so I'm going to post my code.

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application Excel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
Excel.Workbooks.Add();
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet Worksheet = Excel.ActiveSheet;
```

And with this code I am working with my only Sheet, but now I want to add another one with MMPP name but I can't ...
After this I would like to make a dynamic table in the Worksheet MMPP.
Can you help me a little?

Thank you for read and try to help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to understand the object model. At a high level, it goes like this:

- `Application`

  - `Workbooks`

    - `Workbook`

      - `Sheets`

        - `Worksheet`

          - `Range`

A `Workbook` object has two properties that expose a `Sheets` object: `Sheets` and `Worksheets` - the `Sheets` collection holds many types of sheets (`Chart` sheets, for example); if you want to be sure to get a `Worksheet` object, use the `Worksheets` collection.

To create a new worksheet, invoke the `Add` method of the `Worksheets` collection:

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
```

```
var app = new Application;
var books = app.Workbooks; // grab a reference to the collection object; you'll want to clean it up later
var wb = books.Add();
var sheets = wb.Worksheets; // grab a reference to the collection object: you'll want to clean it up later
var sheet = sheets.Add();
```

Adding a worksheet will make that sheet the `ActiveSheet`, but you don't need to care for that - use your `sheet` object/variable to manipulate the new sheet.

The `ListObjects` property of your `sheet` is a collection of all named tables on the sheet, so similarly, you'd invoke `sheet.ListObjects.Add` to create a new `ListObject` on that sheet. Refer to the documentation, it's full of examples.

Comment: Wow @MathieuGuindon thank you a lot for your time! It's so helpfull this for me. To be honest It's my first time with this and is a little hard...

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a sheet to `Sheets` collection of the workbook.

```
var Excel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
var name = "some_name";
var wb = Excel.Workbooks.Add();
var sheet = wb.Sheets[name];
```

Comment: @EyIM But replacing my code? and after that how can I use for example worksheet 1 or worksheet 2? Ty !!!

Comment: It's not replacing your code. wb variable is the Workbook and sheet is the sheet you added.